# angular displaying data *NgFor details

Tags: angular, ngfor

it is possible to displaying data from selected *ngFor to another page?
for example 
i have 2 page `result.component.html` and `details.component.html`

`result.component` is displaying data using *ngFor 
`details.component` is displaying details of data from `result.component`

any idea ?

Comment: Just pass it as `@Input()` parameter

Comment: It's a bit too broad for a question here. Although, it's a simple example that is directly on angular's site.

Comment: Yes its possible. Share your code, let see what you have tried and perhaps someone will correct you where you are wrong.

Comment: sorry im new in angular, any link for example or lesson ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is component interaction. In the parent component you can have your *ngFor and within that *ngFor you can specify the child conponent, something like below:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of allData">
    <child-component inpData="data"></child-component>
</div>
```

and inpData can be declared as @Input in child-component.

For more details on component interaction follow [Angular - Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)